# Why ServletContext value is different for internal and external calls of the same project?

Tags: servlets, attributes

```
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ServletContext sc  = (ServletContext) getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        out.println("sc  = " + sc);
    }
```

...

```
> The result for internal call (http://local-server-ip:8080/prj/Servlet1) :
  sc  = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@1d57f3c

> The result for external call (http://example.com/prj/Servlet1) :
  sc  = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@135542b
```

Why are they different ? if they are different how can we get a ServletContext attribute which is supposed to be application-wise ?

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: They are not necessarily different, they are hidden by a facade. IMHO it is all about the servlet engines' internal design. See e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.catalina/com.springsource.org.apache.catalina/6.0.18/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContextFacade.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the two accesses come from different URLs, the servlet contexts are not supposed to be the same. If you are experiencing a similar problem, please use the same URL both when accessing the project and in the source  of the project, as well. This will also avoid security issues of Ajax calls, too.